# Find out which fields to modify on drupal view for a module

Tags: 7, hooks

I would like to implement a hook on a view that grabs the fields that would be displayed and modifies one of the slightly before displaying it.  However, I am stuck at the first part which is just finding out how to view/see the fields that I can manipulated.  Based on a couple of other post I have read it seems like I should use the parseurl_views_pre_render which seems to make sense.  But, I don't even only how to see what the data looks like.

Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you need with [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7).

Here is what you can do to find out what the data you need to manipulate looks like:

1. Install & enable the devel module - https://drupal.org/project/devel
2. Create a custom module (if you haven't already)
3. Add a function based on HOOK_views_pre_render(&$view)
4. In your function, use the dpm function like so: dpm($view);
5. Reload the page with the view you want to alter
6. Explore the data rendered through [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) which is provided by devel

So, ultimately, your function will start something like this:

```
function your_module_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if (($view->name == 'viewname') && ($view->current_display == 'displayname')) {

    dpm($view);
```

Comment: Thanks Dave this is very helpful and spot-on the information I needed.